# how i do this in oracle pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, hierarchical-data

I have the follow table: example:
nodes:

```
id_node   id_parent
--------------------
1         3
3         2
2         -1
```

I want to insert in other table the level of descent. For example:

#### ancestor:

```
id_node  id_parent  level
-------------------------
1        3          1
3        2          1
1        2          2
```

Comment: What? Why is there a mismatch between the last rows?

Comment: Your data sets don't make any sense.  Please take some time to explain more clearly what it is you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
SELECT id_node, id_parent, level
FROM nodes
START WITH id_parent = -1
CONNECT BY PRIOR id_node = id_parent
```